# "{" and "}" SendKeys.Send-Methode Converter

Tags: c#

I want to use the `SendKeys.Send-Methode`.

The `{` and the `}` have a special meaning. My Text does Contain `{` and `}` though.

So I want to convert my text first. I thought about something like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "blub{ibu{blab}blab";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(convertForSendKey(text));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string convertForSendKey(string password)
    {
            if (password.Contains('{'))
            {
                string[] parts = password.Split('{');
                string tmp = parts[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    tmp += "{{}" + parts[i];
                }
                password = tmp;
            }
            if (password.Contains('}'))
            {
                string[] parts2 = password.Split('}');
                string tmp2 = parts2[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < parts2.Length; i++)
                {
                    tmp2 += "{}}" + parts2[i];
                }
                password = tmp2;
            }
            return password;
    }
```

Of course it wont work like that because in the second `if` it will convert all the `{{}` parts as well, which it should not.

Comment: What is the result you're expecting to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
static string EscapeChar(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '{':
            return "{{}";
        case '}':
            return "{}}";
        default:
            return c.ToString();

    }
}

public static string ConvertForSendKey(string password)
{
    return String.Concat(password.Select(EscapeChar));
}
```

If it works, it first uses LINQ extension method `Select` to project each character onto its relevant string. It then uses `Concat` to glue all the short strings together.

Comment: @AgentFire But the problem was that we needed to perform _two_ replacements in one run. That's why I though `string.Replace` wasn't easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`{{`** or **`\{`** for that symbol escaping. Same thing for **`}}`** and **`\}`**

Also, you have a bad code for character replacement.
Try using [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
string one = "abc";
string two = one.Replace("c", " dd");

// two is "ab dd".
```

Comment: To specify brace characters, use "{{}" and "{}}".
from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

It works fine for the first IF but then i have "{{}" in the string which will be converted in the second IF to "{{{}}" which is not wat is supposed to happen...